# How to play flv stream using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, stream, media-player

In my app, I have a buffer recieving flv stream data. As flv is not supported on Android, then how to play it? If I transform the flv stream buffer to mp4, another problem comes, that is:
How to define the data source of MediaPlayer, as it is a file path or a url usually. Can anybody help or give me some advices.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `VideoView.setVideo(uri)` to set a video in the `VideoView`. You can simply convert a video on the server side or your own pc with this [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) command line:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.flv outfile.mp4
```

Like you should know the function `VideoView.setVideo()` expects as the first parameter a `Uri` which can be a local path or a http/https url.

If you need to send cookies for the download/streaming with your webserver you can use the hidden function `setVideo(Uri, Map<String, String>)` with reflection:

```
HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
header.put("Cookie", "--value--");
Method setVideo = videoView.getClass().getMethod("setVideoURI", Uri.class, Map.class);
setVideo.invoke(videoView, Uri.parse(url), header);
```

But note that you need to catch the possible exceptions which could be throws, for simplification I removed them in the code above.